# What software tools can I use to track the execution of test procedures in a manufacturing setting?

Tags: database

I work for a small engineering and manufacturing company. In my organization, every unit is tested by a checkout tech, according to a written test procedure. We're in the process of updating and improving all those procedures.

We'd like to digitize the whole thing. I imagine we could have a server running somewhere that the checkout tech logs into via a web browser. They see the relevant procedure for the unit they're testing, on a PC or laptop or tablet or whatever. They check the boxes as they go through the procedure, so they know when they're done. They're always running the latest procedure, and all the records get stored electronically. We save on paper, and we should reduce the error rate.

The best proposal I've heard so far is to just roll our own database forms, but I feel like that must be reinventing the wheel. There has to be software to support this sort of thing already in existence. But I can't figure out what search terms to use to find it. What am I looking for? Or am I solving the problem the wrong way?

Comment: You will also save test time if past experience is anything to go by - almost everywhere I have seen manual testing with paper forms the testers name/id, date of test and unit under test serial number needs to be written on every sheet - doing in interactively you would only enter it once.  You can also pop-up thinks like test point locations & HV warnings.